# Is it possible to translate a shape in html5?

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to know if Html5 supports shape translation in canvas..For instance I have a rectangle,is it possible to apply a transformation to it?

```
canvas = document.getElementById('Canvas');
context =canvas.getContext('2d');
context.rect(myRectangle.x,myRectangle.y,myRectangle.width,myRectangle.height);
```

Comment: did you try these http://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#transformations ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, once it is drawn to the canvas you can't change it anymore, there is no in-memory representation of the shapes you draw on the canvas. However, you can [transform](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#transformations) the canvas before you draw the shape and reset transform (`canvas.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)`) after you've drawn the shape.

**Edit**

Remember that the canvas API doesn't keep track of which objects you draw. It just fills the pixels with a color where you ask it to draw a rectangle. If you want to make animations, you will have to keep track of which rectangle you drawn yourself (make an object with properties x, y, width, height). Then you will have to do the following in each animation step:

1. clear the canvas
2. update the objects for the new time frame
3. redraw the canvas

You can find a tutorial [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Basic_animations).

Comment: Then if I have multiple shapes,will all of them be transformed?

Comment: Do you want to make animations?

Comment: Yes I wanted to make animations

Comment: Canvas doesn't keep track of the objects you draw. You will have to redraw the whole canvas on every animation frame. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Or you can use inline SVG with CSS animations instead of canvas in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

There's a few different methods for animating and changing the position that you want to draw your thingy. Either way, if you're after an animation, you're going to need to clear your canvas and keep drawing - like a flip book if you will.

Choices for setting the newly drawn item include:

- moveTo - to move to the new position of your thing
- translate - to translate the centre point of the canvas and keep the drawing positions the same, but move the underlying coordinate system
- .rect(newX, newY, height, width) - drawing the specific position

I mocked together a (contrived) example of using `translate` on a canvas - which will move the the animating box around the position of your cursor. It's done in a loop - and I'd suggest checking out Paul Irish's article on [requestAnimFrame](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) for better animation loops. Here's the example: http://jsbin.com/afofur/2/edit#preview

As the comments say in the previous answer - SVG maintains a object model, so you can reference objects on the page, canvas is a bitmap API (basically), and once the pixels are committed to the canvas, there's no reference to the method or shape behind the drawing, it's just pixels to the canvas API.